# Is cable news on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Broadcast news is an important part of television.  **Is it considered on-topic to ask about television news?**  And if so, *what kind of restrictions are there*, given that news stations and personalities vary in their reach (and therefore notability)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It is not.

Television news is not on-topic here. You can refer to [this help center article](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> > - Identifying a movie or TV series
> > - Locating or purchasing movie or TV content
> > - Technology questions about playing content
> > - Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.
> > - **TV news, sports and current affairs**
> > - A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.
> > - Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

Comment: Not [fully off topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75270/how-did-the-show-comcast-newsmakers-work-on-cnn-headline-news)